# convert radio buttons to star rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to convert the radio buttons in the form to star rating

I am using nintex forms and the way it has DOM structure for the radio button is as below

```
<table class="controls rating">
<tr>
<td>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="review-rating" id="1" value="1" />
        <label for="1">1</label>
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="review-rating" value="2" id="2" />
        <label for="2">2</label>
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="review-rating" value="3" id="3" />
        <label for="3">3</label>
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="review-rating" value="4" id="4" />
        <label for="4">4</label>
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>
        <input type="radio" name="review-rating" value="5" id="5" />
        <label for="5">5</label>
    </span>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I found a jsfiddle which does what I expected, but the dom structure was different

I made some tweaks and got the radio buttons appear as star, but its not working as expected

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/8cn2mekf/)

**I want the star rating on top to work like the star rating in bottom.**

[image]

P.S: Its ok if the bottom one doesn't work after changes. I just want the star rating to be working for my DOM structure(top one in fiddle)

Comment: Putting the stars in a table is a very outdated way of doing this, is there a specific reason you're doing it as I'd strongly advise against it. Also, the fiddle you provided seems to work absolutely fine

Comment: your fiddle is working , what is the problem in it ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I don't option to change the way the form(DOM Structure). I can only add CSS/Script to make it work in the DOM structure. try clicking 2nd star and 4th star on the top star rating

Comment: @SoniVimal the bottom star rating works fine. I want the star rating on top to work like it. Try clicking 2 and 4 in the top star rating

Comment: why do you need it to store in a table?

Comment: @NewbeeDev I don't option to change the DOM structure in the technology that I am working on. It just builds the html form like this. So no other go

Comment: @vignesh you want a function that work on this both structure?

Comment: no, just the top one needs to work. bottom one is just for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I just added the undo

```
$('.controls.rating')
    .addClass('starRating') //in case js is turned off, it fals back to standard radio button
    .on('mouseenter', 'label', function(){
            DisplayRating($(this)); // when we hover into a label, show the ratings
        }
    )
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        // when we leave the rating div, figure out which one is selected and show the correct rating level
        var $this = $(this),
            $selectedRating = $this.find('input:checked');
        if ($selectedRating.length == 1) {
            DisplayRating($selectedRating); // a rating has been selected, show the stars
        } else {
            $this.find('label').removeClass('on'); // nothing clicked, remove the stars
        };
    }
);

var DisplayRating = function($el){
    // for the passed in element, add the 'on' class to this and all prev labels
    // and remove the 'on' class from all next labels. This stops the flicker of removing then adding back
    $el.addClass('on');
    $el.parent('label').addClass('on');
    $el.closest('td').prevAll().find('label').addClass('on');
    $el.closest('td').nextAll().find('label').removeClass('on');
};
```

Edit: I just notice a bug lately so I edited it and fix the bug

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8cn2mekf/8/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem: your "label" are not next to each other. Convert css and event select to your "td".

[https://jsfiddle.net/8cn2mekf/1/](http://Fiddle)

Comment: because, onmouse leave the star rating doesn't seem to undo.

Comment: $this.find("td").removeClass('on'); change else statement to this

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `find` to remove the `on` class on deeper nodes `children` only works on level one child nodes

https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/z1sws1w7/